# how to format several cell ranges at once in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-tables

[image]

I have several of these "tables" (not actually a table format) spanning over 900 rows, is there anyway I could delete/add rows and apply these changes to all of them?

Also, if there are formulas for each of the cells, would the formulas transfer over to the modified sections of these "tables"?

Tried user Power Query Editor, had no luck (first time user, all I found is that it just turned all the mini tables into one properly formatted table, which I don't want)

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly. Can you give me an example?

Comment: The cells in everything but the first 2 columns have formulas. In specific, I am trying to remove 'Chantel's' row and the 2 rows by themselves at the bottom and have this change apply to all other tables like this in the sheet.